# Unable to parse array of dictionary inside string

Tags: ios, json, swift

Currently I am working on bus booking module. After user set his departure and arrival city and date of journey, user will be shown a list of available buses. I have done that part successfully. But the problem which I am facing is that, each bus has it's own cancellation policy which is array of dictionary inside string. I am unable to parse it. Inside every dictionary of "apiAvailableBuses" there is "cancellationPolicy" key which has string as value which contains array of dictionary. I have removed other key value pairs from "apiAvailableBuses".

List of available Buses JSON response:

```
"apiAvailableBuses":[
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
   },
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"9-12\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"25\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"12-24\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"35\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"24-48\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"50\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"48-60\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"75\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"60\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
   },
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
   },
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
   },
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
   },
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
   },
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
   },
   {
      "cancellationPolicy":"[{\"cutoffTime\":\"6-24\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"70\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"24\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"85\"}]"
   }
]
```

Can anyone help me with a solution for this? If anyone can't understand my question please let me know.

Note: I am not using Codable in my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think key `cancellationPolicy` contains json-string. You can deserialize json-string and can use.

Comment: Are you responsible for the backend? If yes, send a dictionary rather than a nested JSON string which must be *second-level-deserialized*

Comment: Hi @vadian, we are using api's of a third-party which provide bus booking api's.

Comment: Then make it more understandable by adding some code to show what you have tried so far and so we can see if there are any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse JSON string using the following method:

```
// JSON Format
    let jsonResponse = ["apiAvailableBuses": [
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
        ],
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"9-12\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"25\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"12-24\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"35\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"24-48\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"50\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"48-60\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"75\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"60\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
        ],
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
        ],
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
        ],
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
        ],
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
        ],
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
        ],
        [
            "cancellationPolicy": "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"6-24\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"70\"},{\"cutoffTime\":\"24\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"85\"}]"
        ]
        ]
    ]

// Function Calling
        setBuses(json: jsonResponse)

// Function to Parse JSON
func setBuses(json: Dictionary<String,Any>) {
    guard let buses = json["apiAvailableBuses"] as? [Dictionary<String,Any>] else { return }
    for (index, bus) in buses.enumerated() {
        print("\n\nBus #\(index+1)")
        guard let policies = convertToDictionary(text: bus["cancellationPolicy"] as! String) else { return }
        for (index, policy) in policies.enumerated() {
            print("\nPolicy #\(index+1)")
            print("cutoffTime #\(index+1) \(String(describing: policy["refundInPercentage"]))")
            print("refundInPercentage #\(index+1) \(String(describing: policy["cutoffTime"]))")
        }
    }
}

func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [Dictionary<String,Any>]? {
    let data = text.data(using: .utf8)!
    do {
        if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options : .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String,Any>] {
            return jsonObj
        } else {
            print("JSON Error")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Hi Bhavik, "cancellationPolicy" key is inside "apiAvailableBuses" which is again array of dictionary. How can I get string value from "cancellationPolicy" key.

Comment: You can get that by normal JSON parsing.

Comment: I have updated my question. We are not using Codable in project.

Comment: @YashJadhav check the updated answer. It will help you to parse JSON to your custom model object.

Comment: Hi Bhavik, convertToDictionary function is missing in solution.

Comment: @YashJadhav Sorry mate! updated the same. please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194175/discussion-between-yash-jadhav-and-bhavik-modi).

Answer (score 0):

Use **`Codable`** to parse the above `JSON response`.

If your `JSON response` have the below format:

```
{
  "apiAvailableBuses": [
    {
      "cancellationPolicy": [
        {
          "cutoffTime": "5",
          "refundInPercentage": "90"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Create `Codable types` to parse the above response.

```
struct AvailableBuses: Codable {
    var apiAvailableBuses: [Bus]
}

struct Bus: Codable {
    var cancellationPolicy: [CancellationPolicy]
}

struct CancellationPolicy: Codable {
    var cutoffTime: String
    var refundInPercentage: String
}
```

In the above code, I've created 3 `struct` conforming to `Codable protocol` - `AvailableBuses, Bus, CancellationPolicy`

**Usage:**

After getting `data` from your `API response`, you can `parse` the it using the above created `structs` like,

```
if let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let availableBuses = try JSONDecoder().decode(AvailableBuses.self, from: data)
        print(availableBuses)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have not used Codable in my project. So, can the solution be achieved without using Codable.

Comment: If you haven't then you must now. Because this is the what is recommended and is much efficient and easy to use than other solutions.

Comment: You are right. But using Codable only for this one problem in entire project is not ok. That's the reason I am looking for solution other than using Codable.

Comment: @YashJadhav Codable is a part of Foundation and thus built-in so why wouldn’t it be ok to use it?

Comment: The value of `cancellationPolicy` is a plain **string**, a nested JSON string, not an array of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Codable` for some reason, you can use `JSONSerialization`.

```
let input = "[{\"cutoffTime\":\"5\",\"refundInPercentage\":\"90\"}]"
let data = input.data(using: .utf8)!
let parsed = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! Array<Dictionary<String, Any>>

print(parsed) // [["refundInPercentage": 90, "cutoffTime": 5]]
```

Comment: Hi @wvteijlingen, "cancellationPolicy" key is inside "apiAvailableBuses" which is array of dictionary. How can I get string value from "cancellationPolicy" key.